# SSRS textbox height issue?

Tags: reporting-services, textbox, ssrs-2012

I have a page header in my ssrs report and in the page header i have two text boxes side by side, in preview time textbox heights are increasing according to data, so what is happening one text box height is more and another is less. I want that both textbox size should always be same if there is 4 line data in 1st textbox and only 1 line data in textbox 2. Please guide me what can i do?
For reference i have added screenshot.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does your three textboxes requires to have a border each?

Comment: yes it requires. I tried table header and removed table rows instead of textboxes but problem is that table is not repeating on every page.